# Saturn Date Picker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material-datetimepicker

I am trying to implement the saturn datepicker and below is my code. Unfortunately, I notice that after January 4th (Wednesday), January 5 starts only on a Sunday.

For the month of February ...Feb 01 is on a Sunday and Feb 02 is also on the following Sunday.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput
      placeholder="Choose a date"
      [satDatepicker]="picker"
      [value]="date">
  <sat-datepicker #picker [rangeMode]="true"></sat-datepicker>
  <sat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></sat-datepicker-toggle>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: Saturn Datepicker showing wrong days]

Comment: What is the version you are using?

Comment: The version is :   "saturn-datepicker": "^8.0.1",

Comment: it's looks like work well in the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cfnyl, see that in your image you has not the "name of the month" Are you using some to remove? better use `color:transparent` that a `display:none`

Comment: That was it! The display label was set to none. Thank you very much!